# Accidentally deleted a folder's contents in iPython/Jupyter and I can recover it from trash on Mac OSX Yosemite. Is there anyway I can get it back?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, ipython

Just installed iPython/Jupyter and accidentally deleted pictures from a file that was living on my desktop. I don't know how to undo what I just deleted and can't seem to find any of the pictures in my trash. Is there anyway I can recover them? My instance of iPython/Jupyter is still open.

Thanks.

Comment: You might need a file recovery program, especially if you used `os.remove(...)`

Comment: Use a file recovery program, and don't install it to the same drive you are recovering from - install it to a memory stick or another drive on the machine. Try to avoid using the computer for anything else until you have recovered your files, since using it may use the freed space for something new, reducing the recoverability of the lost data.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't easily recover the files. The files are gone. Your option is to restore from a backup, or use a data recovery tool of some sort.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I just need to be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the hidden directory ".ipynb_checkpoints" inside of the directory that used to hold the notebook.

If you had recently been running the notebook prior to deleting it, you may be able to find a recent copy of it saved at the last "checkpoint".